# Set Xbox controllers order on Windows

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, xbox-one, windows

I have an Xbox One controller and an Xbox 360 controller plugged in my PC.
Windows always set the 360 controller as the primary (number 1), but I want the One controller to be the primary.

If I unplug and then plug in again the 360 controller it is still the primary controller.

Comment: Have you tried switching up the USB ports? The OS assigns interface numbers to them and might always assign the lowest number player one.

Comment: @Eric I tried swapping USB ports (with PC turned off), but the order is still the same

Comment: Have you tried starting with just the One controller and then plugging in the 360 controller once the One controller has been assigned to the primary player?